# Can't enable SoftDeleteable in Symfony2 - Unrecognized options "filters"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm having problems trying to activate the **SoftDeleteable** filter in **StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle**. I configured it as described in the [manual](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst):

```
# app/config/config.yml
doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                filters:
                    softdeleteable:
                        class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                        enabled: true
```

But this is what I get:

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
Unrecognized options "filters" under "doctrine.orm.entity_managers.default"
```

Running `bin/vendors update` didn't help. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, using `bin/vendors update` is a bad idea because it sets all the vendors to their latest versions. You should use `bin/vendors install` only.

Second, make sure you are using the `1.0.x` branch of `StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle`, because the `master` branch is not compatible with Symfony `2.0.x`.

Comment: Thanks, `master` does seem to contain a bc break so we switched to `1.0.x`. Unfortunately it lacks support for doctrine filters so it looks like we'll have to do without SoftDeleteable for now.

Answer (score -1):

You can just do it yourself, it is not hard, saving you from installing another bundle:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/filters.html

Comment: If there is an extension, why reinvent it?